# java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to boolean

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have big problem. Runing the app using Android Emulator works good, but when I put the app on a real phone i get this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to boolean (found in field 'imp')
```

My Firebase data is OK, 'imp' field is a boolean in the database, so what I'm retrieving  is a boolean from databae and storing it in a boolean var. How can it say that I receive a Long when the data is sent from Firebase as a Boolean?

**Why is this happening only with a real phone**?

Now I really don't understand why in Android Emulator works fine and installing the app in a real phone gives me this error.

This is my adapptor who is handling the data:

```
public class modelNoutati  {

String name;
String cont;
Date data;
Boolean imp;

public modelNoutati(){ }

public modelNoutati(String cont, Date data, Boolean imp, String name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cont = cont;
    this.data = data;
    this.imp = imp;
}


public String getName() {return name;}

public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

public Date getData() {return data;}

public void setData(Date data) {this.data = data;}

public String getCont() {return cont;}

public void setCont (String cont) {this.cont = cont; }

public Boolean getImp () {return imp;}

public void setImp (Boolean imp) {this.imp = imp;}
```

I get the issue here on **doc.getDocument().toObject(modelNoutati.class)**

```
for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()){

                if(doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {

                    modelNoutati newsInt = doc.getDocument().toObject(modelNoutati.class);
                    newsL.add(newsInt);

                    newsAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Logcat:

```
Process: projects.nv.umcstudent, PID: 14354
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to boolean (found in field 'imp')
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeym.zzc(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeym.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeym.zzb(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeym.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeym$zza.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeym.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeym.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(Unknown Source)
    at projects.nv.umcstudent.News$1.onEvent(News.java:70)
    at projects.nv.umcstudent.News$1.onEvent(News.java:57)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzi.onEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeyn.zza(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeyo.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: show your lgocat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following line of code:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to boolean (found in field 'imp')
```

Tells you exactly what the problem is. Your `imp` property is declared in your model class as a `Boolean` but when you are trying to get the value of this property from the database you are getting a `Long`. There is no way in Java in which you can convert the `Long` to a `Boolean`.

To solve this, you need to clear your database and add fresh data in which the `imp` property will hold a `Boolean` value as in your model class, and not a `Long` value.

Comment: My firebase data was corrupted somehow..deleting the document and creating new ones solved it.

Comment: Hi Alex, For some reason i want to show some default values when data is corrupted. I don't want my app to crash. I just don't where should i catch this exception ?

Comment: @Bikash I recommend you post another fresh question, so me or oher users can help you.

Comment: Sure @AlexMamo. Please find the link to my question 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849305/how-to-catch-java-lang-runtimeexception-could-not-deserialize-object-from-fireb

Answer (score 4):

Check your Database, if your data type is accurate then follow these two methods.As you said that this problem only occurs on a real device so there is no problem with the data type ,it is accurate.

I was facing this same problem,this problem can be solved by two methods:

1.Removing the entire collection and then adding the data back again.I tried this and I don't recommend this method,because adding the data back requires lot of effort especially if you are working with tons of data.

2.Uninstall the app and then re-install it.If you tried the first method and it did not help this this will definitely work.It's the easiest of the two method and does not require that much effort.

For me, the second method worked but for some the first might work.
**Use the second method.It is easy and does not require that much effort.**

Answer (score 0):

This is not a big issue you are only trying to get the wrong casting type.
Go to your database and check `imp` **property** in all the records. Certainly you have mistakenly entered the wrong data type for this.

It should be boolean type but in one of your record it is wrongly entered as long.

you should also add try catch block around this mapping.

```
try{
    modelNoutati newsInt = doc.getDocument().toObject(modelNoutati.class);
                    newsL.add(newsInt);

                    newsAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
}catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: No bad entry. Just checked...that why i dont understand.(i have only 4 docs). I checked more than 10 times,belive me

Comment: The problem is that in emulator works fine-thats why im telling you my entries are ok. When installing it on a phone it gives me this error. shouldn't  the emulator give me the error when running the app on it? String(firebase)-String(app var) says that firebase string is a Long, Boolean to Boolean says olso is a string , BUT ONLY ON REAL DEVICE! WHY?

Comment: show your database buddy because today morning i faced this issue i just do two things to resolve this error create a no argus constructor and check into the db for data type.

Answer (score 0):

Declare imp as `int` in your class `modelNoutati` and declare it as a `String` in your class database handler. Your imp equals 0(`false`) or 1(`true`).
I hope that help you :)

Comment: if i do that its giving me this error.. java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to int (found in field 'imp') ....and this is normal - not the same entry tipe

Comment: `int imp = Integer.parseInt(_imp); //_imp getting from database`