# How to catch java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object from Firebase ClassMapper and add default Values

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I am using Firebase UI Recycler Adapter to read data from Firestore

```
FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Transaction> options =
                new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Transaction>()
                        .setQuery(mQuery, Transaction.class)
                        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
                        .build();

        mAdapter = new TransactionAdapter(options, this, getActivity()) {

            @Override
            public void onDataChanged() {
                // Show/hide content if the query returns empty.
                if (getItemCount() == 0) {
                    mRestaurantsRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mRestaurantsRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                Log.e("Error", ", not initializing RecyclerView",e);
            }
        };
        Log.w("Test", "No6 query, not initializing RecyclerView");
        mRestaurantsRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mRestaurantsRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

i am getting below exception for some corrupted fields in Firestore

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not deserialize object. Failed to convert a value of type java.lang.String to double (found in field 'amount')
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeError(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:524)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertDouble(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:427)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToPrimitive(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:304)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:215)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToType(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:180)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.access$200(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:53)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:700)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:674)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:503)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:242)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:97)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:203)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:121)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:183)
    at com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot.toObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@17.1.4:101)
    at com.firebase.ui.firestore.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:23)
    at com.firebase.ui.firestore.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:12)
    at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(BaseCachingSnapshotParser.java:35)
    at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:52)
    at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java:83)
    at com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirestoreRecyclerAdapter.java:125)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6673)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6714)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5647)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5913)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3225)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:739)
```

I know why this error is thrown and i also know i can correct this if i correct my amount field in Firestore Database or by having a Cloud Function to check data validation etc.

But I don't want an App crash experience. Is there any way to catch and add any default value or Null for corrupted values. Showing an individual Null or NA field or an entire empty screen is always better than a Crash.

**EDIT:**
In order to set a default value and avoid Runtime exception i have tried this with my Model class. I still don't know if there is a way to catch this exception.

```
public double amount;
public double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
// If you change it Object, ClassMapper will not throw any exception and 
// You can parse any data type by yourself and also set a default value.
public void setAmount(Object amount) {
    try {
        // You can also add  instanceOf check
        this.amount = Double.parseDouble(amount.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Set your default value
        this.amount = 0.00;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding an `onError` handler? https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/firestore#data-and-error-events

Comment: onError handler method is never executed.

Answer (score 4):

I'm answering this question becase of your request from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49614685/java-lang-runtimeexception-could-not-deserialize-object-failed-to-convert-valu/49627405?noredirect=1#comment94546214_49627405). So because I see that you are using the Firebase-UI library, there is no need to use a try-catch block. As also @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, the simplest thing that you can do, is to override the `onError` method in your adapter class like this:

```
FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Chat, ChatHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    public void onDataChanged() {
        //Called each time there is a new query snapshot.
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
        //Handle the error
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Bikash! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: onError method is not working, i had that handler from start

Comment: Why do you say it's not working, what's the behaviour? Do you have an error or? Is this `e.getMessage()` printing something?

Comment: onError() method is never called for the above exception and if i am not wrong i think that onError will handle only Query or snapshot related exception but not POJO Mapping (gson).

Comment: But is the `onDataChanged()` method even called?

Comment: Yes, please check my updated code snippet. I am even able to get itemCount with getItemCount() method. I am able to get the data but error is thrown in onBindViewHolder method of recycler adapter from CustomClassMapper deserialise call

Comment: In that case, you should use an if statement or a switch statement that sounds like this. If your property is an instance of Long, then print the Long value, else if, your property is an instance of String, print la value String otherwise print nothing or anything you want, right?

Comment: FirebaseUI automatically assigns property to my Model Class. So I have change my Model class variables (double/Data) to Object and It is not crashing now.

But i was looking for a better way to handle this or at least be able to catch such exception.

Comment: I understood. Do you think that my answer/comments helped you?

Comment: You were great ! but frankly the moment i got the exception i had change my Model class to avoid this exception. Please check my latest edit. I can't think of any better way to do this !
But I still don't know how to catch this Exception :(

Comment: But that's not a bad solution as you might think.

Comment: Hi I am also facing same exception but while fetching data from firestore and parsing it to the model class. How can I handle it there? I want to assign default value if deserlization failed. In ios, we can handle it using decoder.

Comment: @ShyamalyLakhadive You can achieve the same thing here. You can map a document into an object of a type of your choice.